# Django form ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, imagefield

I'm trying to establish CreateView for the model which holds ImageField. I can successfully upload and display images from django admin page. But, when I upload images from my own form, django doesn't upload images to "upload_to" folder. I'm writing my codes below:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='album_logos', default='album_logos/no-image.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Album
class AlbumCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'title',
            'artist',
            'release_date',
            'logo'
        ]
```

views.py

```
class AlbumCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = AlbumCreateForm
    template_name = 'music/album_create.html'
    success_url = '/albums/'
```

album_create.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I try to create album using "album_create.html" and upload image with django's default form, logo image isn't uploaded to "album_logos" folder and takes default value. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try this, logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='album_logos') and check any stacktrace

Comment: I've tried. Without default value django says "This field is required." above imagefield input form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I changed album_create.html by specifying "enctype" attribute for the "form" tag as stated in django documentation and my problem is solved.

**DOCUMENTATION**

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

A view handling this form will receive the file data in request.FILES, which is a dictionary containing a key for each FileField (or ImageField, or other FileField subclass) in the form. So the data from the above form would be accessible as request.FILES['file'].

Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the  that posted the request **has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.**

---

**UPDATED album_create.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may Help You

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
class PictureWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        html =  Template("""<img src="$link"/>""")
        return mark_safe(html.substitute(link=value)

class AlbumCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    logo = ImageField(widget=PictureWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'title',
            'artist',
            'release_date',
            'logo'
        ]
```

And aslo add in form tag add this property

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @ElginCahangirov check my latest answer

Comment: I can't run server with your code. It says invalid syntax. Can't find out where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I've commented my own code, then copied and pasted your code. Now, with your code server can't be run.

Comment: "/home/elgin/Desktop/python/pycharm/django/muplay/music/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/elgin/Desktop/python/pycharm/django/muplay/music/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .forms import AlbumCreateForm
  File "/home/elgin/Desktop/python/pycharm/django/muplay/music/forms.py", line 25
    class AlbumCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can you add latest  form

Comment: It doesn't work. TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'

Comment: `NameError: name 'ImageField'` is not defined :(

Comment: can define your modal and django version

Answer (score 0):

All I got to do is add

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

in album_create.html

```
`{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}`
```

and then, initializate the form as:

```
form_class= AlbumCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

in views.py

I recommend you visit this page [GeeksforGeeks ImageField](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagefield-django-forms/)